# uitableview custom transparent header

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using section headers to show a small image 'floating' next to cells from appropriate sections. The section header is transparent and contains only a imageview. 
The initial problem with this solution was that the section header takes up height, which looked strange (there was unnecessary empty space in the beginning of each section + the image should be aligned with the top of the first cell when tableview is scrolled to the beginning of the section). The fix for this was to set section header height to 1px. The image was still in place, but the header didn't use any height and everything looked great.

However now I need to add a UIButton on top of that image, and unfortunately it doesn't work when the header has 1px of height. It is not hidden or covered by anything and it is drawn correctly, but the set selector doesn't get called. If I set some height, the button works.

In short - how to achieve either a working button in a section header that has virtually no height, or how to achieve a section header that has normal height but always overlaps cells (doesn't use any space when the tableview is scrolled to the top of the section)?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So tapping on the section header is always associated with some action?

Comment: Well, actually tapping on a button in the section header.

Comment: Ah, not the entire section header then?

Comment: No. Although if you had a solution for the entire header I could detect if it was touched in the right place. But, as I mentioned earlier, it has height of 1 px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you may be able to get this to work is to add a transparent view over the table. You would intercept touchDown and touchUp. You could calculate whether they were over one of your buttons, and if so send them directly to the button, otherwise just forward them. the reason you don't get the touch events is probably since the touch does not fall into the header frame.

Answer (score 0):

David H suggestion was my initial idea as well but I was hoping to find a more elegant solution. Anyway, that's how I ended up implementing this feature.

I kept the code as simple as possible (I'm sure it can be done in a more optimized fashion, works fast enough for my needs) - each image added to a section (no need for overlaying buttons anymore) was also added to a dictionary with section numbers as keys.
When my mask layer view (the transparent one added over my tableview) is being touched I simply check with `CGRectContainsPoint` if the touch corresponds to any of the views in my dictionary.